# How to add ETH as parameter when calling solidity contract function on web3

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I have created smart contract with function:

```
function putOrder() external payable {
  require(msg.value == itemPrice);
  (bool sent, bytes memory data) = shopManager.call{value: msg.value}("");
  require(sent, "Failed to purchase");
}
```

This just checks if eth/bnb value is properly passed to the function and then sends it to manager address.

This is how my function on web3 with react looks like:

```
const putOrder() = async () => {
    ...
  window.contract.methods.orderStuff().send({from: accounts[0]}).on(
    'receipt', function(){
      processOrder();
    }
  );
    ...
}
```

Obviously I get an error that itemPrice is not met. So how do I pass eth/bnb value to send trough web3 to contract function call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass it to the `send()` function argument as a property named `value`. Its value is the amount of wei (not the amount of ETH) to be sent.

It's just an override of the [transaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction) params (the transaction that executes the contract function). So you could also use it to override `gas` value, `nonce` and other params if you need.

```
.send({
    from: accounts[0],
    value: 1  // 1 wei
})
```

```
.send({
    from: accounts[0],
    value: web3.utils.toWei(1, 'ether')  // 1 ETH == 10^18 wei
})
```